# Jailbreak simulator to test jailbreak measure

Tags: android, ios, react-native, ios-simulator, jailbreak

I'm really new to react native and am developing an app that is not operable on jailbroken device.
Now, I'd like to test if the jailbreak measures really work. Is it possible to test it without an actual jailbroken device? For example, using a simulator that is jailbroken?
And also, is it possible to jailbreak a simulator? If so, how? Thanks a lot!